# Opening/Closing the modal window triggers window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In my angular app, i use modal windows for filters/selectors and there are many components which are binded with window resize event like SVG, wordcloud etc.. Whenever i open or close the modal window, it triggers window resize event which results in reloading of all those components (Charts)..

Is there a way to stop the triggering of window resize event while opening or closing the modal window..?.. I googled and got a thread about this issue which is still open..

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2309

Comment: Use absolute positioning, i.e. `position: fixed` for the dialog.

Comment: You may be able to `preventDefault` on the event, but I'd have to see the code for a more directed solution. Do you mind posting the relevant sections of code (how is the modal opened, closed, etc.)? Are you using Angular-ui modal or something else?

Comment: @KeenanLidral-Porter I am using angular-ui modal and opening, closing in the same way like how it is in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: As I see opening modal does not trigger window resize when using angular only.

Comment: please create a plnkr demonstrating your problem...

Comment: your problem is just open modal situation.
it means you disable the resize bind when modal open.
after than rebind the resize event.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak http://codepen.io/shprink/pen/CFxiG.. Check here..

Comment: @PetrAveryanov It triggers..

Comment: [Did you see this?](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2817)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `window.resize` is triggered intentionally by the framework itself -- [from the source: `ionic.trigger('resize');`](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/service/modal.js#L163).

### solution

#### option 1

You can just comment out the above mentioned line and create your own bundle of the ionic framework.

#### option 2

You can use decorator to replace `$ionicModal` service altogether by copying and modifying the source code. Let me know if anything unclear. I personally prefer this option as it should be easier to maintain in the long run and let you customise the behaviour of the modal even further.

[**HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYBGeZ?editors=001) is an example of what I mean:

```
.config(function($provide){
  $provide.decorator('$ionicModal',function($rootScope, $ionicBody, $compile, $timeout, $ionicPlatform, $ionicTemplateLoader, $q, $log) {

    var PLATFORM_BACK_BUTTON_PRIORITY_MODAL = 200;

    var delegate = (function(){

  /**
   * @ngdoc controller
   * @name ionicModal
   * @module ionic
   * @description
   * Instantiated by the {@link ionic.service:$ionicModal} service.
   *
   * Be sure to call [remove()](#remove) when you are done with each modal
   * to clean it up and avoid memory leaks.
   *
   * Note: a modal will broadcast 'modal.shown', 'modal.hidden', and 'modal.removed' events from its originating
   * scope, passing in itself as an event argument. Note: both modal.removed and modal.hidden are
   * called when the modal is removed.
   */
  var ModalView = ionic.views.Modal.inherit({
    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name ionicModal#initialize
     * @description Creates a new modal controller instance.
     * @param {object} options An options object with the following properties:
     *  - `{object=}` `scope` The scope to be a child of.
     *    Default: creates a child of $rootScope.
     *  - `{string=}` `animation` The animation to show & hide with.
     *    Default: 'slide-in-up'
     *  - `{boolean=}` `focusFirstInput` Whether to autofocus the first input of
     *    the modal when shown.  Default: false.
     *  - `{boolean=}` `backdropClickToClose` Whether to close the modal on clicking the backdrop.
     *    Default: true.
     *  - `{boolean=}` `hardwareBackButtonClose` Whether the modal can be closed using the hardware
     *    back button on Android and similar devices.  Default: true.
     */
    initialize: function(opts) {
      ionic.views.Modal.prototype.initialize.call(this, opts);
      this.animation = opts.animation || 'slide-in-up';
    },

    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name ionicModal#show
     * @description Show this modal instance.
     * @returns {promise} A promise which is resolved when the modal is finished animating in.
     */
    show: function(target) {
      var self = this;

      if (self.scope.$$destroyed) {
        $log.error('Cannot call ' +  self.viewType + '.show() after remove(). Please create a new ' +  self.viewType + ' instance.');
        return;
      }

      var modalEl = angular.element(self.modalEl);

      self.el.classList.remove('hide');
      $timeout(function() {
        $ionicBody.addClass(self.viewType + '-open');
      }, 400);

      if (!self.el.parentElement) {
        modalEl.addClass(self.animation);
        $ionicBody.append(self.el);
      }

      if (target && self.positionView) {
        self.positionView(target, modalEl);
        // set up a listener for in case the window size changes
        ionic.on('resize',function() {
          ionic.off('resize',null,window);
          self.positionView(target,modalEl);
        },window);
      }

      modalEl.addClass('ng-enter active')
             .removeClass('ng-leave ng-leave-active');

      self._isShown = true;
      self._deregisterBackButton = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
        self.hardwareBackButtonClose ? angular.bind(self, self.hide) : angular.noop,
        PLATFORM_BACK_BUTTON_PRIORITY_MODAL
      );

      self._isOpenPromise = $q.defer();

      ionic.views.Modal.prototype.show.call(self);

      $timeout(function() {
        modalEl.addClass('ng-enter-active');
      //  ionic.trigger('resize');
        self.scope.$parent && self.scope.$parent.$broadcast(self.viewType + '.shown', self);
        self.el.classList.add('active');
        self.scope.$broadcast('$ionicHeader.align');
      }, 20);

      return $timeout(function() {
        //After animating in, allow hide on backdrop click
        self.$el.on('click', function(e) {
          if (self.backdropClickToClose && e.target === self.el) {
            self.hide();
          }
        });
      }, 400);
    },

    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name ionicModal#hide
     * @description Hide this modal instance.
     * @returns {promise} A promise which is resolved when the modal is finished animating out.
     */
    hide: function() {
      var self = this;
      var modalEl = angular.element(self.modalEl);

      self.el.classList.remove('active');
      modalEl.addClass('ng-leave');

      $timeout(function() {
        modalEl.addClass('ng-leave-active')
               .removeClass('ng-enter ng-enter-active active');
      }, 20);

      self.$el.off('click');
      self._isShown = false;
      self.scope.$parent && self.scope.$parent.$broadcast(self.viewType + '.hidden', self);
      self._deregisterBackButton && self._deregisterBackButton();

      ionic.views.Modal.prototype.hide.call(self);

      // clean up event listeners
      if (self.positionView) {
        ionic.off('resize',null,window);
      }

      return $timeout(function() {
        $ionicBody.removeClass(self.viewType + '-open');
        self.el.classList.add('hide');
      }, self.hideDelay || 320);
    },

    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name ionicModal#remove
     * @description Remove this modal instance from the DOM and clean up.
     * @returns {promise} A promise which is resolved when the modal is finished animating out.
     */
    remove: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.scope.$parent && self.scope.$parent.$broadcast(self.viewType + '.removed', self);

      return self.hide().then(function() {
        self.scope.$destroy();
        self.$el.remove();
      });
    },

    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name ionicModal#isShown
     * @returns boolean Whether this modal is currently shown.
     */
    isShown: function() {
      return !!this._isShown;
    }
  });

  var createModal = function(templateString, options) {
    // Create a new scope for the modal
    var scope = options.scope && options.scope.$new() || $rootScope.$new(true);

    options.viewType = options.viewType || 'modal';

    angular.extend(scope, {
      $hasHeader: false,
      $hasSubheader: false,
      $hasFooter: false,
      $hasSubfooter: false,
      $hasTabs: false,
      $hasTabsTop: false
    });

    // Compile the template
    var element = $compile('<ion-' + options.viewType + '>' + templateString + '</ion-' + options.viewType + '>')(scope);

    options.$el = element;
    options.el = element[0];
    options.modalEl = options.el.querySelector('.' + options.viewType);
    var modal = new ModalView(options);

    modal.scope = scope;

    // If this wasn't a defined scope, we can assign the viewType to the isolated scope
    // we created
    if (!options.scope) {
      scope[ options.viewType ] = modal;
    }

    return modal;
  };

  return {
    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name $ionicModal#fromTemplate
     * @param {string} templateString The template string to use as the modal's
     * content.
     * @param {object} options Options to be passed {@link ionic.controller:ionicModal#initialize ionicModal#initialize} method.
     * @returns {object} An instance of an {@link ionic.controller:ionicModal}
     * controller.
     */
    fromTemplate: function(templateString, options) {
      var modal = createModal(templateString, options || {});
      return modal;
    },
    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name $ionicModal#fromTemplateUrl
     * @param {string} templateUrl The url to load the template from.
     * @param {object} options Options to be passed {@link ionic.controller:ionicModal#initialize ionicModal#initialize} method.
     * options object.
     * @returns {promise} A promise that will be resolved with an instance of
     * an {@link ionic.controller:ionicModal} controller.
     */
    fromTemplateUrl: function(url, options, _) {
      var cb;
      //Deprecated: allow a callback as second parameter. Now we return a promise.
      if (angular.isFunction(options)) {
        cb = options;
        options = _;
      }
      return $ionicTemplateLoader.load(url).then(function(templateString) {
        var modal = createModal(templateString, options || {});
        cb && cb(modal);
        return modal;
      });
    }
  }


    })();
    console.log(delegate);

    return delegate;

  });
})
```

### caution

Changing the behaviour *may have* some unwanted side effects, but I do not know ionic framework that much. Moreover, if there are any negative side effects then surely that is a bad design of the framework itself, as general events should not be used for framework specific purposes. If I had a bit more time I will try to make a PR to have triggering of the event optional.